# How to insert backgroun image in card in react?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, core-ui

I want to insert an `image` as background in card.I have saved the `image` in public/img/login.png .The `image` isn't shown..I'm using coreui react admin template.This is my code ::

```
<CCard className="text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none " style={{ width: '44%' , backgroundImage: "url(/login.png)" }}>
  <CCardBody className="text-center ">
     <div>
        <h2>Sign up</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <Link to="/register">
          <CButton color="primary" className="mt-3" active tabIndex={-1}>Register</CButton>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </CCardBody>
</CCard>
```

Comment: Is your `login.png` image in correct directory?

Comment: You said you have the image in `public/img/login.png`. I think the url should be `/img/login.png`

Comment: I changed it to /img/login.png but the result was the same

Answer (score 0):

You have created a assest folder inside of your root folder then you can add a images folder there and take the relative path and import it in the background image url.

import the image

```
import Yourimage from '../images/background_image.png';

var imgStyle= {
  backgroundImage: `url(${Yourimage})`
};

class ImgComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div style={imgStyle}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it but the result was the same.. Thank you for your guidance

Comment: Have tried to change the img path?  Please try to change the path (../..) according to your file location

Comment: I added an img element under ccard element so it was resolved. <CCard className="text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none " style={{ width : "44%"}}>
                <img src={"./img/login.png"} />

Answer (score 0):

you can add an image element to it.

```
import YourImage from "../images/image.jpg";
```

make sure you import your image first. I put my image on the folder where it is easy to access. After that you simply have to add this:

```
<img src={YourImage} className="card-imp-top" alt="..." />
```

or modify your image however you wish!!